# Adjustable Excel Range with a criteria?

Tags: excel-formula

This is a bit difficult to explain but I am trying to create a formula that will use a referenced cell for a given range and return the most recent date found with that referenced cell. I have seen formulas such as Max(If(... but my problem is that each referenced cell has a different amount of dates to look through to find the most recent date. 
For Example

```
Cell Reference         Formula Returns  
A                      6/1/2015  
B                      5/15/2015  
C                      6/7/2015  
D                      5/29/2015  

Range to be used        Dates  
A                       1/15/2015  
A                       2/23/2015     
A                       4/24/2015  
A                       6/1/2015  
B                       1/28/2015  
B                       12/25/2014  
B                       10/22/2014  
B                       5/15/2015  
B                       4/20/2015  
C                       2/28/2015  
C                       6/7/2015  
D                       2/14/2015  
D                       5/29/2015  
D                       10/30/2014
```

Hope that visual helps.
Thanks

Comment: Figured it out. Rather than doing a formula I just organized the data by first alphabetical then by date newest to oldest. From there just did a remove duplicates and it gave me the newest date for each of the entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: `=MAX(IF($A$8:$A$21=$A2,$B$8:$B$21,0))` entered with ctrl-shift-enter.